# github actions path filtering returning true when no changes made

Tags: github-actions, cicd

So I'm using this marketplace action `dorny/paths-filter` to check if there are files changed to run a specific workflow. for the moment I'm just testing the outputs to see if they are correct so I have this file structure.

```
- .github/workflows/
- scraper_backend/
- terraform_ecr/
- terraform_lambda
- app.py
- tagging.sh
```

Now I want 3 workflows for when there is a change to either the `backend`, `terraform_ecr` or `terraform_lambda`. So I just `echo` the output of to see if they found a change but when there is no change to either of these 3 folders it still returns `true` for the `backend` and the `lambda` folder. This is my workflow

```
name: Composite Test
on: [pull_request, push]
jobs:
  changes:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      backend: ${{ steps.changes.outputs.backend }}
      ecr: ${{ steps.changes.outputs.infra }}
      lambda: ${{ steps.changes.outputs.lambda }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2
      id: changes
      with:
        filters: |
          backend:
            - 'scraper_backend/**'
            - 'app.py'
            - 'tagging.sh'
          ecr:
            - 'terraform_ecr/**'
          lambda:
            - 'terraform_lambda/**'
  test:
    needs: changes
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: echo ${{ needs.changes.outputs.backend }}
      - run: echo ${{ needs.changes.outputs.ecr }}
      - run: echo ${{ needs.changes.outputs.lambda }}
```

This is the output

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

#### EDIT

I think it compares to the `main` branch where it detects the changes. Is there a way to tell it to look at the latest commit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it.

```
steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2
      id: changes
      with:
        base: ${{ github.ref }} <----- ADDED
        filters: |
          backend:
            - 'scraper_backend/**'
            - 'app.py'
            - 'tagging.sh'
          ecr:
            - 'terraform_ecr/**'
          lambda:
            - 'terraform_lambda/**'
```

Just needed to add this `base` line

Comment: `base` only works if triggered by `push`. For `pull_request` event this is ignored.